# A question about null sets and measure of intersection.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ a measure space and let $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$. Suppose that $$\mu(A)=0,\;\mu(B)\ge0$$

Can I conclude that $\mu(A\cap B)=0$?

It would seem so, in fact $$0\le\mu(A\cap B)\le\mu(A)=0.$$ But if I consider $$\mu(A\cap B)\le\mu(B)$$ I can't conclude anything about the measure of $A\cap B.$

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know whether $\mu$ is a [complete measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure)?

Comment: No, $\mu$ is a generic measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A = \big(A\cap B\big) \cup \big( A\smallsetminus B\big)
$$
and these two sets whose union is taken are disjoint. Therefore
$$
0 = \mu(A) = \underbrace{\,\mu(A\cap B) \,\,+\,\, \mu(A\smallsetminus B)}_\text{sum of two nonnegative numbers}.
$$

Comment: I have not understood what I can conclude from this.

Comment: @JackJ. : If the sum of two nonnegative numbers is $0$ then they're both $0. \qquad$

Comment: $A=(A\cap B)\cup(A\setminus B)$, true?

Comment: @JackJ. : Yes. Fixed. $\qquad$